# Rails ActionMailer ignores settings in environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I put my ActionMailer config in my `config/environment.rb` file like so:

```
MyApp::Application.initialize!
MyApp::Application.configure do

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: "smtp.elasticemail.com",
      port: 2525,
      domain: "myapp.com",
      authentication: "plain",
      user_name: "my_username",
      password: "my_password",
      enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

end
```

My understanding is that this is the correct way to configure settings that will apply to all your environments.

This worked fine in development, but when I deployed to my staging server (which uses a custom `config/environments/staging.rb` config file) I got a "connection refused" error when it tried to deliver mail. `staging.rb` has no mailer-related settings in it at all.

So I fired up the console on the staging server with `RAILS_ENV=staging rails c`, and "puts Rails.application.config.action_mailer" shows that the settings I put in `environment.rb` are indeed in effect, but for some reason ActionMailer is not using them.

Through experimentation I found that copying the config directly into `staging.rb` solves the problem. Why is this necessary? If the rails console shows the settings are in effect, why isn't ActionMailer using them?

Digging deeper, I see that my mailer class's delivery_method is not set as expected:

```
MyMailer.foo(Person.find(1)).delivery_method

 => #<Mail::SMTP:0x0000000370d4d0 @settings={:address=>"localhost", :port=>25, :domain=>"localhost.localdomain", :user_name=>nil, :password=>nil, :authentication=>nil, :enable_starttls_auto=>true, :openssl_verify_mode=>nil, :ssl=>nil, :tls=>nil}>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

put

```
MyApp::Application.configure do

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: "smtp.elasticemail.com",
      port: 2525,
      domain: "myapp.com",
      authentication: "plain",
      user_name: "my_username",
      password: "my_password",
      enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

end
```

before `MyApp::Application.initialize!`

Comment: I'd really like to see the Stackoverflow SQL logs for when my question was posted vs when you answered (and solved) it... had to be < 30 seconds.

Comment: Great question! Great answer! Solved a knotty problem for me.